# From concavity to convexity

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose I have a function $g$ on $[-1,1]$ which is increasing, concave and such that $g(-1)=0$. I set $h(t)=\frac{g(t)}{1+t}$. Is it true that $h$ is decreasing and convex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $g(x)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

Hence, with $h(x)=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{x+1}$ there are problems.

Comment: Are you sure? Because to me this is not a counter-example.

Comment: @Babyblog $g$ is an increasing and concave, which you wish.

Comment: But $h$ is decreasing and convex. My question is: is it true that for all such $g$ and $h$ we have $h$ convex and decreasing?

Comment: @Babyblog My $h$ is not convex. $h''(0)<0$

Comment: Ok you're wright your $h$ is concave. Thank you.